# Query plan on indexed partitioned table. Avoid sequential scan

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a postgres 10.1 server I have a very big table partitioned by list value and a view which only filterthe table by the partition column.

When using the view, the planner is not giving me the best possible plan, i mean, scanning only the selected children tables.
Instead it always scans all partitions of the parent table.

I have created a index by the partition column and a constraint tool.
The DDL:

```sql
                                  Table "parted_mob_matrix"
    Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer               |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 delivery_id  | integer               |           |          |         | Partition key: LIST (delivery_id)
Partitions: parted_mob_matrix_delivery_0 FOR VALUES IN (0),
            parted_mob_matrix_delivery_1 FOR VALUES IN (1),
            parted_mob_matrix_delivery_10 FOR VALUES IN (10),
            ....
            parted_mob_matrix_delivery_10 FOR VALUES IN (620),


                            Table "parted_mob_matrix_delivery_620"
    Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id           | integer               |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 delivery_id  | integer               |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
Partition of: parted_mob_matrix FOR VALUES IN (620)
Partition constraint: ((delivery_id IS NOT NULL) AND (delivery_id = ANY (ARRAY[620])))
Indexes:
    "parted_mob_matrix_delivery_620_delivery_id_idx" btree (delivery_id)
Check constraints:
    "parted_mob_matrix_delivery_620_check_delivery" CHECK (delivery_id = 620)
```

Mi view code:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT
  parted_mob_matrix.*
FROM
  parted_mob_matrix
1) where parted_mob_matrix.delivery_id in (620)
2) where parted_mob_matrix.delivery_id in (select 620)
```

I need to use the `2` version here simplified (It's a real query to another very little table) but it plans very different and worse.

QUERY PLAN 1 (good on efficency):

```
Append  (cost=0.00..78308.11 rows=758031 width=738)

  ->  Seq Scan on parted_mob_matrix_delivery_620  (cost=0.00..78308.11 rows=758031 width=738)

        Filter: (delivery_id = 620)
```

QUERY PLAN 2 (rowset, slow):

```
Hash Semi Join  (cost=0.01..25077311.20 rows=7539693 width=860)

  Hash Cond: (parted_mob_matrix_delivery_0.delivery_id = (620))

  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..24942162.20 rows=211111399 width=859)

        ->  Seq Scan on parted_mob_matrix_delivery_0  (cost=0.00..10.75 rows=250 width=294)

        ->  Seq Scan on parted_mob_matrix_delivery_1  (cost=0.00..10.75 rows=250 width=294)

 -- All the child tables

        ->  Seq Scan on parted_mob_matrix_delivery_620  (cost=0.00..77929.09 rows=758031 width=738)

 -- All the child tables are scanned
```

How can I use the plan `1` on a query which a where like `2`?

Comment: You can't.  Pruning the partitions happens at compile-time.  The results of the subquery are not known at compile-time, so the query needs to look at all partitions.

Comment: This has been improved in Postgres 11 and will even be better in Postgres 12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve your problem in PostgreSQL v10 wrapping the input of WHERE condition as an IMMUTABLE plpgsql function which returns an ARRAY of integers. By definition, an IMMUTABLE plpgsql function *"(...) allows the optimizer to pre-evaluate the function when a query calls it with constant arguments (...)"* (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/xfunc-volatility.html).

This solution should work.

Example:

```sql
SELECT
  parted_mob_matrix.*
FROM
  parted_mob_matrix
WHERE parted_mob_matrix.delivery_id = ANY(get_deliveries('cod_011'))
```

The function you could use:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_deliveries(
    high_level_id TEXT
)
RETURNS INTEGER[]
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    _delivery_ids INTEGER[];
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format(
    $$
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(delivery_id)
    FROM
        your_table_with_all_delivery_ids
    WHERE
        high_level_id = '%1$s'
    ;
    $$, high_level_id
  ) INTO _delivery_ids;
  RETURN _delivery_ids;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: It runs geat! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using PostgreSQL v10, where *partition pruning* only happens at plan time.

In your first query, the condition is a constant, so that partition pruning can take place. In the second case, it is a subquery result (that is not flattened), so it won't work.

Run `EXPLAIN` on both queries to see the difference.

You should use PostgreSQL v11, where partition pruning can also happen at query execution time.